# Node.js – events js 72 throw er unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Node.js and wish to run a program using streams. With other programs, I had to start a server simultaneously (mongodb, redis, etc) but I have no idea if I'm supposed to run one with this. Please let me know where I am going wrong and how I can rectify this.

This is the program:

```
var http = require('http'),
feed = 'http://isaacs.iriscouch.com/registry/_changes?feed=continuous';


function decide(cb) {
setTimeout(function () {
if (Date.now()%2) { return console.log('rejected'); }        
cb();
}, 2000);
}

http.get(feed, function (res) {

decide(res.pipe.bind(res, process.stdout));


//using anonymous function instead of bind:
// decide(function () {
//   res.pipe(process.stdout)
// });

});
```

This is the cmd output:

```
<b>C:\05-Employing Streams\05-Employing Streams\23-Playing with pipes>node npm_stre
am_piper.js

events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: Parse Error
at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1583:20)
at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)
</b>
```

Comment: Are you sure the URL http://isaacs.iriscouch.com/registry/_changes?feed=continuous is right? I get nothing from there, but I do get something from http://isaacs.iriscouch.com/registry/changes?feed=continuous (without the underscore). Also see [here](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) for an example of how to catch errors from http.get.

Answer (score 90):

Close `nodejs app` running in another shell.
**Restart** the terminal and **run** the program again.

---

Another server might be also using the same port that you have used for nodejs. **Kill** the process that is using `nodejs port` and **run** the app.

To find the PID of the application that is using **port:8000**

```
$ fuser 8000/tcp
8000/tcp:            16708
```

Here PID is **16708** Now kill the process using the `kill [PID]` command

```
$ kill 16708
```

Comment: This error can also be thrown if your Node app is expecting to connect to a port which is not available, even if it's not being used by another process. For example, my app was expecting to connect to a port on a Vagrant box I set up, but I had not started that box.

Comment: @sheldonkreger, could you please elaborate on this issue with opening a port in vagrant? because i think that i am having the same issue (i get this error when trying to run a meteorjs app inside a vagrant box). thanks!

Comment: The issue was that my Vagrant instance was not running at all. That's why the port was unavailable! :-)

Comment: If the port number is occupied, then most probably you will see such an error message.

Comment: i tried what you said but $ fuser 80/tcp returned nothing, can you suggest me where i am going wrong.

Comment: @samartajShaikh it's because nothing is running on port 80.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. I closed terminal and restarted node.  This worked for me.

Comment: This solved this for me,

Because, I was running this using port-30,   and was trying to run it again on same port in other terminals .

lol


yes this solved it . closing the terminals :P

Answer (score 3):

Well, your script throws an error and you just need to catch it (and/or prevent it from happening). I had the same error, for me it was an already used port (EADDRINUSE).

Comment: @Adam You need to use other port number or kill the server that is using your port.

Comment: A little old, but try handling the 'error' event on the event emitter. Works for me. Example

emitter.on('error', function (error) { ... });

Answer (score 2):

I always do the following whenever I get such error:

```
// remove node_modules/
rm -rf node_modules/
// install node_modules/ again
npm install // or, yarn
```

and then start the project

```
npm start //or, yarn start
```

It works fine after re-installing node_modules. But I don't know if it's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Check your terminal it happen only when you have your application running on another terminal..

The port is already listening..

Answer (score -3):

For what is worth, I got this error doing a clean install of nodejs and npm packages of my current linux-distribution
I've installed meteor using

```
npm install metor
```

And got the above referenced error. After wasting some time, I found out I should have used meteor's way to update itself:

```
meteor update
```

This command output, among others, the message that meteor was severely outdated (over 2 years) and that it was going to install itself using:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

Which was probably the command I should have run in the first [place](https://www.meteor.com/install).

So the solution might be to upgrade/update whatever nodejs package(js) you're using.