# Node.js event.js:72 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have a problem with my app. One year ago when I want to run the server everything was fine. Now I need to implement few things and when I start server in cmd used node app.js it throw this error pleas help

Serwer HTTP działa na pocie 3000

> events.js:72
>               throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>                     ^
>       Error: Ready check failed: undefined
>           at RedisClient.on_info_cmd   (C:\Users\Agnieszka\Desktop\TSW\makao\node_modules\redis\index.js:325:35)
>           at Command.callback   (C:\Users\Agnieszka\Desktop\TSW\makao\node_modules\redis\index.js:373:14)
>           at RedisClient.flush_and_error   (C:\Users\Agnieszka\Desktop\TSW\makao\node_modules\redis\index.js:129:25)
>           at RedisClient.connection_gone   (C:\Users\Agnieszka\Desktop\TSW\makao\node_modules\redis\index.js:429:10)
>           at Socket.   (C:\Users\Agnieszka\Desktop\TSW\makao\node_modules\redis\index.js:94:14)
>           at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
>           at _stream_readable.js:944:16
>           at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly because another app is using the port you are trying to use

Ganesh answered this well here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25369114/4151025

Hope it helps, else you would have to show some code

Comment: So i try to do like thi but it doesn't work. I try to run it on cloud 9 and there is the same error

Comment: can you share the code of your main file (server.js or app.js or anything you called it)

also since you said you wrote the code a long time ago, maybe you should try updating the packages

Comment: I think the issue is socketio.listen, 

it tries to start another server, causing the issue

I am really not sure though because your code is a bit old, rewriting it may save you many headaches