# Error: spawn ng build --watch --output-path while running gulp

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm new to Angular, when I try running gulp in the angular folder, I get the following error:

```
[08:24:14] Using gulpfile .../angular/gulpfile.js
[08:24:14] Starting 'styles'...
[08:24:14] Starting 'angular'...
[08:24:14] Finished 'angular' after 6.44 ms
[08:24:14] Starting 'server'...
[08:24:14] Finished 'server' after 19 ms
[08:24:14] Starting 'watch'...
[08:24:14] Finished 'watch' after 53 ms
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn ng build --watch --output-path ../../public/angular/dist ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:469:11)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
```

I have already followed a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39872252) and tried:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install
```

But, still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Given your error message, it looks like your gulp task is calling:

`spawn("ng build --watch --output-path ../../public/angular/dist")`

Spawn requires arguments to be passed separately from the initial command, so you should use

`spawn("ng", ["build", "--watch", "--output-path", "../../public/angular/dist"])`

instead.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar problem with NPM angular script on windows, there are couple of thing you can check.

**Step 1. Add below code to the top, so that you know which command has problem**

```
  /** add below childProcess logic to troubleshoot what's wrong if error happens. */
  var childProcess = require("child_process");
  var oldSpawn = childProcess.spawn;
  function mySpawn() {
      console.log('spawn called');
      console.log(arguments);
      var result = oldSpawn.apply(this, arguments);
      return result;
  }
  childProcess.spawn = mySpawn;
  spawn = childProcess.spawn;
```

**Step 2. If you run your application on windows, you may need to use ng.cmd; otherwise, for other os, please use ng.sh**

```
  const isWindows = /^win/.test(process.platform);
  const commandFileExtension = isWindows ? 'cmd' : 'sh';
  let child = spawn(`ng.${commandFileExtension}`, ['build']);
```