# Can't build production package

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, jhipster

- NPM version (npm --v): 5.4.2
- Gulp version (gulp -v): CLI@1.4.0, Local@3.9.1
- JHipster version: 4.6.1
- Node version: 6.11.3

I'm unable to build a production package. Running the application completes without issues and the same goes for building a package with 'dev' profile.

For some reason when I run ".\mvnw -Pprod package" on the project's root directory I get this error:

```
[INFO] [17:15:22] Starting 'inject:vendor'...
[INFO] [17:15:22] Starting 'ngconstant:prod'...
[INFO] [17:15:22] Starting 'copy:languages'...
[ERROR] events.js:160
[ERROR]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[ERROR]       ^
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Error: File not found with singular glob: D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\src\main\webapp\.htaccess
[ERROR]     at Glob.<anonymous> (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\glob-stream\index.js:41:11)
[ERROR]     at Glob.g (events.js:292:16)
[ERROR]     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
[ERROR]     at Glob.emit (events.js:188:7)
[ERROR]     at Glob._finish (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\glob.js:172:8)
[ERROR]     at done (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\glob.js:159:12)
[ERROR]     at Glob._processSimple2 (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\glob.js:652:12)
[ERROR]     at D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\glob.js:640:10
[ERROR]     at Glob._stat2 (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\glob.js:736:12)
[ERROR]     at lstatcb_ (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob\glob.js:728:12)
[ERROR]     at RES (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\inflight\inflight.js:31:16)
[ERROR]     at f (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
[ERROR]     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25.257 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-02T17:15:22+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/467M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:gulp (gulp build) on project agora: Failed to run task: 'gulp build --no-notification' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I understand what it's telling me, I'm missing the .htaccess file but I never needed it before. I recently moved the project from my main drive to the backup drive and since then I can't generate a production package.

If I create an empty ".htaccess" where gulp needs it I get this other error:

```
[INFO] [17:21:43] Finished 'inject:app' after 2.94 s
[INFO] [17:21:43] Starting 'inject:troubleshoot'...
[INFO] [17:21:43] 'inject:troubleshoot' errored after 1.01 ms
[INFO] [17:21:43] Error: Invalid glob argument:
[INFO]     at Gulp.src (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\src\index.js:32:11)
[INFO]     at Gulp.troubleshoot (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\gulp\inject.js:61:27)
[INFO]     at module.exports (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
[INFO]     at runNextSet (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:123:15)
[INFO]     at Gulp.onTaskEnd (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:101:4)
[INFO]     at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
[INFO]     at Gulp.emit (events.js:188:7)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
[INFO]     at D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
[INFO]     at finish (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
[INFO]     at D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:52:4
[INFO]     at f (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
[INFO]     at DestroyableTransform.onend (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:31:18)
[INFO] [17:21:43] 'build' errored after 3.98 s
[INFO] [17:21:43] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(inject:troubleshoot)'
[INFO] Message:
[INFO]     Invalid glob argument:
[INFO] Stack:
[INFO] Error: Invalid glob argument:
[INFO]     at Gulp.src (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\src\index.js:32:11)
[INFO]     at Gulp.troubleshoot (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\gulp\inject.js:61:27)
[INFO]     at module.exports (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
[INFO]     at runNextSet (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:123:15)
[INFO]     at Gulp.onTaskEnd (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:101:4)
[INFO]     at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
[INFO]     at Gulp.emit (events.js:188:7)
[INFO]     at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
[INFO]     at D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
[INFO]     at finish (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
[INFO]     at D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:52:4
[INFO]     at f (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
[INFO]     at DestroyableTransform.onend (D:\GitHub\Agora\AgoraWeb\node_modules\orchestrator\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:31:18)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.220 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-02T17:21:43+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/367M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:gulp (gulp build) on project agora: Failed to run task: 'gulp build --no-notification' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

(Sorry for the long logs)

I have tried many things, including the full deletion of the repo and cloning it again. I've also tried clearing NPM's cache as advised in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841204/events-js160-throw-er-unhandled-error-event). At this point I don't know what else to try.

Thanks !!

Comment: Once on Windows I got issues because node was installed on C: and project was on D:, I put all on same drive and it worked. which version of node?

Comment: Using node 6.11.3. But I noticed jhipster installs a local node inside the project's directory. I'll try to move node to the backup drive too, thanks for the help ! :)

Comment: The local node is indeed used for prod builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Gaël Marziou put me in the right track to investigate conflicting versions of node or gulp.

After testing various versions of node, both local and global I tried disabling gulp tasks one by one, none of them helped me really even though the error messages did change. So I tried messing with gulp versions, and that was the answer.

I solved my problem by changing the following line in my package.json:

```
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
```

to this:

```
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
```

And now everything builds perfectly.

Thank you very much :)