# events.js:167 throw er; //Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, error-handling

```
Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch '/home/me/Desktop/Edu/Web/JS/React/weather_app/public'
```

I have over 700gb free space on my HDD, so don't think it is related to the error.

!After the error it became unavailable to run `'npm start'` on any project present on my machine.

Today I started work on my project that I left yesterday evening in a perfectly working state. I wanted to add `redux` to my React project. Steps I made were:

1. Initializing a local git repository and commiting the key importance files
2. Downloading redux and react-redux packages via npm
3. npm start - here the trouble started

OS: ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Node.js version: 10.7.0

npm version: 6.2.0

Also I have tried couple of options suggested on GitHub and this one => [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782463/node-events-js167-throw-er-unhandled-error-event)

Comment: This space is not related to to total hard disk but allocated to your app

Comment: Can you give me more specifications, so I can google a solve method for that? :) 
Or simply an advise on how to enlarge the space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run the below command to avoid ENOSPC:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

After that execute:

```
sysctl --system
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default browser worked for me. I am actually not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

My AVG Antivirus labeled electron.exe as a malicious file and removed it from the project directory. Restoring it from the quarantine and adding an exception on AVG removed the error for me