# Unhandled error during starting create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I've created a new project through create-react-app. After the project successfully created, I'm trying to start the project by hitting command `yarn start` but it throws me an unhandled error.

Anyone has a good solution to this problem.

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch /home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/public ENOSPC
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:232:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:414:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/sagar/w    Starting the development server...

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch /home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/public ENOSPC
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:232:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:414:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:462:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:467:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.orkspace/code-splitting/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:462:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/sagar/workspace/code-splitting/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:467:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js – events js 72 throw er unhandled 'error' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960703/node-js-events-js-72-throw-er-unhandled-error-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the problem you can follow this steps.

First, reinstall `node_modules`:

```
rm -rf node_modules/ && npm i
```

Then, start the project:

```
npm start
```

or

```
yarn start
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the dependencies is the solution.

Delete the node_modules directory

and then:

```
yarn install
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall node modules using `npm install`
and do

`npx create-react-app my-app
 cd my-app
 npm start`

Answer (score 0):

credit: @robininfo-edsx
"The current error is a ENOSPC (Not enough space)
It's not directly related to permission but normally to disk usage and when you hit the limit of file you can watch.
As root the limit of watch is probably bigger than a normal use,that's why sudo solve the problem however run an application as root is not desirable.
Try to increase the limit of watchable files
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc/32600959#32600959"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475849/node-js-error-enospc/32600959#32600959%22)

Answer (score -1):

Found solution on https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3486#issuecomment-346485194

```
sudo yarn start
```